# Your APK cannot be analyzed using 'aapt dump badging'. Error output:

Tags: android, dump, aapt, gamesalad

I use Gamesalad to create my apps for both Apple and Android. Gamesalads process allows me to create an APK without having to manually use eclipse and the sdk. Gamesalad creates my APK and normally I would simply zip it, then upload to the Google Play Developer Console without issue. I haven't uploaded an APK to Google Play in about a year recently tried, only to receive the following error:

```
Upload failed
Your APK cannot be analyzed using 'aapt dump badging'. Error output:
Failed to run aapt dump badging:
ERROR: dump failed because assets could not be loaded
Upload another APK
```

I've never had to run the aapt dump badging for any of the APKs I've uploaded to Google Play using Gamesalad before so I am at a total loss here.